# Adding elements to a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to Python and I am trying to add elements to a 3D list.

```
def getHoughSpace(self):
        space = [[[]]]
        for i in range(0, len(self.xs)):
            rho = self.getRho(self.xs[i], self.ys[i], self.zs[i])
            space.append([Cell(rho, 0)])
            for j in range(0, len(self.ys)):
                theta = self.getTheta(self.xs[j], self.ys[j], self.zs[j])
                space[i].append([Cell(theta, 0)])
                for k in range(0, len(self.zs)):
                    phi = self.getPhi(self.xs[k], self.ys[k])
                    space[i][j].append([Cell(phi, 0)]) # error happens here
```

However, when `i=1`, `j=0`, and `k=0`, my program crashes with the error:

```
AttributeError: Cell instance has no attribute 'append'
```

Why is this happening? How can I get passed `i=0`, `j=0`, and `k=0` but not when `i=1`? Obviously, I am accessing a Cell at `space[i][j]`, but I want to access the list of `Cells`.

- An interesting note is that if I comment out the error line, it runs. So why does the problem occur only in the 3rd dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to append elements at the end, for the three dimensional list:

```
space = []
space.append([])
space[i].append([])
space[i][j].append(<element>)
```

Or you can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
space = np.empty((len(self.xs), len(self.ys), len(self.zs)), dtype=object)
```

Comment: I used numpy to get it working. I would note that you cannot use append anymore sense you have allocated an array. You must use `space[i][j][k] = Cell(phi, 0)`.

Comment: @TrevorHutto The problem, with original program is: `space.append([Cell(rho, 0)])` which disturbs the dimensionality of list, if you print it you can see another `list` being added as element instead of `list of list`.